# Best Practices for Internationalizing a Flex Application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, internationalization

I am looking into internationalizing a Flex application I am working on and I am curious if there are any best practices or recommendations for doing so.

Googling for such information results in a handful of small articles and blog posts, each about doing it differently, and the advantages and disadvantages are not exactly clear.

Edited to narrow scope:

- Need to support only two languages (en_CA and fr_CA)
- Need to be able to switch at runtime

Comment: @Niko: Take a look at [this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Change_Locale_at_the_runtime-11143.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, after googling a bit more I come across an article on [runtime localization](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:_Runtime_Localization).

And followed these steps:

Add the following to the compiler arguments to specify the supported locales and their path:
(In Flex Builder, select project and go properties -> Flex Compiler -> Additional Compiler Arguments)

`-locale=en_CA,fr_CA -source-path=locale/{locale}`

Create the following files:

```
src/locale/en_CA/resources.properties
src/locale/fr_CA/resources.properties
```

And then the compiler complains: `unable to open 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.1.0\frameworks\locale\en_CA'`

Which looks to be related to bug [SDK-12507](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-12507)

**Work around:**
In the `sdks\3.1.0\bin` directory, execute the following commands:

```
copylocale en_US en_CA  
copylocale en_US fr_CA
```

This will create the locale directories in the Flex Builder installation and build some required resources into them.

Then in your `.mxml` files, reference the resource bundle:

```
<mx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("resources")]
</mx:Metadata>
```

And internationalize the strings:

```
<mx:TitleWindow title="Window Title">
```

becomes:

```
<mx:TitleWindow 
    title="{resourceManager.getString('resources', 'windowTitle')}">
```

and

```
var name:String = "Name";
```

becomes:

```
var name:String = resourceManager.getString("resources", "name");
```

And in your `src/locale/en_CA/resources.properties` file:

```
windowTitle=Window Title
name=Name
```

Comment: How do you accomplish the locale switch runtime, when using resource manager in ActionScript?