# Internationalizing an mx:MenuBar?

Tags: apache-flex, internationalization, flash-builder, flex4.5

Well, I was able to simply enough (after about an hour of googling) implement i18n (internationalization) into my Flex application by *having to reverse engineer the Flex SDK* and do a lot of digging (a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133094/best-practices-for-internationalizing-a-flex-application) on here helped me a lot! (with [some updates for flex 4.5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3a.html))).

The problem is, I can't use my `{getLand('key')}` bind inside an `<fx:XMLList>` (how you define the contents of a `<mx:MenuBar>`.  I've included some example i18n below, as well as an example of the menu bar.

```mxml
<!-- Example of proper (working) i18n -->
<s:TextArea text="{getLang('Rules')}"/>

<!-- Problem Area (a bare bones example) -->
<!-- Error message in IDE: Access of undefined property _application_XMLList1 -->
<mx:MenuBar labelField="@label">
    <fx:XMLList>
        <menuitem label="{getLang('File')}"/>
    </fx:XMLList>
</mx:MenuBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the XMLList outside of the menubar, like so:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  <fx:XMLList id="_menuStuff">
    <menuitem label="{getLang('File')}"/>
  </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:MenuBar labelField="@label" dataProvider="{_menuStuff}"/>
```

That should work, good luck!